# How to edit/change a field in a model without using a form in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

So im creating a Multiple choice quiz and I want to be able to add different quizzes with different difficulty and have around 20 questions for each quiz that i make. From those 20 questions the program should randomly select 10 questions and displays them SEPERATELY. So basically I got the questions to display seperately and created a few models but i also want to save the users results after they have answered the 10 questions to the database and how many times they attempted the same quiz. Is there a way to do this without using a form?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Quizzes(models.Model):

    CHOICES = (
        ('Easy', 'Easy'),
        ('Medium', 'Medium'),
        ('Hard', 'Hard'),
    ) 

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    quizDesc = models.TextField()
    difficulty = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, choices=CHOICES)

    class  Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Quizzes"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name    

class QuestionList(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quizzes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    questNum = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    op1 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    op2 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    op3 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    op4 = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    ans = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)

class userQuizInfo(models.Model):
    username = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quizzes, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    correct = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    wrong = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    questOrder = models.CharField(max_length=10,null=True)
```

views.py

```
questions = list(QuestionList.objects.filter(quiz_id=pk))
    questions = random.sample(questions,1)

    # userInfo = userQuizInfo.objects(pk=pk)
    # userInfo.questOrder += questions
    # userInfo.save()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        correct=0
        wrong=0

        for q in questions:
            if q.ans ==  request.POST.get(q.question):
                correct+=1
            else:
                wrong+=1

        if (correct+wrong) == 10:
            # questList = val()
            context = {
                'correct':correct,
                'wrong':wrong,
            }

            return render(request, 'results.html', context)


        context = {
            'questions':questions,
        }

        return render(request, 'questions.html', context)
    else:
        context = {
            'questions':questions,
        }

        return render(request,'questions.html',context)
```

in my views im basically trying to see if they get the question right and if they do then save it to the database with the attempt. so for example: attempt 2 on quiz 1, question #2: correct and attempt 1 on quiz 1, question #2: wrong. This way i can see the results of each question everytime they attempt the quiz. I also want to save the order in which the questions are shown to the user which is why in my models i made the userQuizInfo model.

questions.html

```
{% block page_content %}

    <h1>Questions: </h1>

    <form method='post'>
        {% csrf_token %}

        {% for q in questions %}
            <h1>{{ q.question }}</h1>
            <input type="radio" name="{{q.question}}" value="{{q.op1}}">{{q.op1}}
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="{{q.question}}" value="{{q.op2}}">{{q.op2}}
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="{{q.question}}" value="{{q.op3}}">{{q.op3}}
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="{{q.question}}" value="{{q.op4}}">{{q.op4}}
        {% endfor %}

        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <!-- <h1>{{ questions.question }}</h1>
    <input type="radio" name="{{questions.question}}" value="{{questions.op1}}">{{q.op1}}
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="{{questions.question}}" value="{{questions.op2}}">{{q.op2}}
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="{{questions.question}}" value="{{questions.op3}}">{{q.op3}}
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="{{questions.question}}" value="{{questions.op4}}">{{q.op4}} -->

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

A form would make parts of this more organized (such as generating the subset of questions and generating the html for the questions) but isn't completely necessary

Instead of storing UserQuizInfo I think it would be better to just make a UserQuiz model that stores each quiz separately (created when the quiz is being given to the user) and fields to indicate which questions were answered correctly or incorrectly (updated when the user submits the quiz). This way you can track exactly what quizzes users were given, if the quiz was submitted, and if the questions were answered correctly/incorrectly. Also storing every question in a separate field instead of one character field would be easy using ForeignKey fields to Questions and would make the model appear more organized in django admin; and storing question correctness in a BooleanField would let you keep it null until the quiz has been turned in, and then you can set it to true/false for each individual question instead of storing the total amount of correct/incorrect.
If needed you could also add an attempt_number integer field to track how what number attempt they are on for the specific quiz (count the number of UserQuiz models with the same user and Quiz)

P.S. Your 'Quizzes' model should be named 'Quiz' since each object represents a single quiz, and 'QuestionList' should just be 'Question' since it represents a singular question.

If you have more questions lmk and I will respond when available

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! 

I'm a newbie when it comes to django and all the stuff you suggested should be done in a form? or is that without a form? 

also when you say to create fields for correct and incorrect, what field should i make and how would i update it when the user takes the quiz? i tried to update a model without a form and it just never worked. 

and i did save the questions in different fields in the questionList, are you saying that way is wrong or just that I named it wrong? 

last, can you help with the assignment of foreignKeys and models since i dont understand it?

Comment: What fields would i create for the userQuiz? I was trying it out rn and can't figure out what fields to use for it. I was thinking to use the username and quiz with foreignKey and then i dont know what field to use for correct or wrong. there would also be a field for questionOrder right? sorry for the bombardment of questions. i just dont understand it